How to convert strings of different units to floats of the same?
I have a panda's dataframe with strings, but I want floats. The units on the strings are different though. One column might be in mm with a few in cm. The next column might be g with a few in kg, and so on.
How can I convert each to floats in the same units? (i.e. if I'm changing everything to floats in mm, then "4.56 cm" should convert to 45.6, not 4.56).

Example
we need minimal and reproducible example to answer.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'length': ['4.56 cm', '100 mm', '3.5 cm', '10 mm'], 
        'weight': ['200 g', '0.5 kg', '300 g', '2 kg']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df:
    length  weight
0  4.56 cm   200 g
1   100 mm  0.5 kg
2   3.5 cm   300 g
3    10 mm    2 kg

Code
I have prepared an answer with a example, but if your situation is different, please create and provide your own clear example.
s1 = df['length'].str.replace('[A-Za-z]', '', regex=True).astype('float')
df['length(mm)'] = np.where(df['length'].str.contains('cm'), s1 * 10, s1)

s2 = df['weight'].str.replace('[A-Za-z]', '', regex=True).astype('float')
df['weight(g)'] = np.where(df['weight'].str.contains('kg'), s2 * 1000, s2)

df:
    length  weight  length(mm)  weight(g)
0  4.56 cm   200 g        45.6      200.0
1   100 mm  0.5 kg       100.0      500.0
2   3.5 cm   300 g        35.0      300.0
3    10 mm    2 kg        10.0     2000.0


I wish there was a library or something that knew all the units and conversion ratios that I could just call. But, as I have only a few units and conversions to be done, this works splendidly! Thank you so much.
